# Ubuntu boot problem - messed up disk parameters

Tags: boot, ssd, rescue-mode

So the other day, I cloned my Ubuntu and EFI boot partitions to new SSD (I have dualboot, so I cloned it while I was on Windows). Everything went ok, I booted normally. My disks now look like this:

[new ssd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQCJs.png)

[old ssd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDbCZ.png)

As you can see, disks have the same UUIDs. Because of this, when I finally decided that I will keep all my disks inside my laptop (which was because Windows would not boot in external encasing), it sometimes booted Ubuntu partition on new ssd, sometimes on old ssd. The best thing I could do (but did not) was just change UUIDS and properly adjust `etc/fstab` file. But I went on changing some settings in Gnome Disks app (I don't rememeber exactly what). In Gnome Disks I went -> `Edit Mount Options..` and here I think I did change some settings [settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2wRh.png). I don't exactly remember what I changed, I guess I unchecked `Mount at system startup` for partition on old ssd and made sure that this chceckbox was check for partiton on new ssd. I also could change something else, but I don't remember (It has been 3 weeks since this). Next I rebooted my laptop and Ubuntu went into rescue mode. I could not boot into system. I googled, and it suggested to do fsck on partition that should be mounted. This did not help and maybe did more bad than good (as internet says). Then when going through `journalctl -xb` logs, I figured out that my system enters some state of error, after wich it can't write onto boot partition. After googling for this, [I adjusted Ubuntu boot parameters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185026/how-to-edit-etc-fstab-when-system-boots-to-read-only-file-system/185031#185031) - on line starting with linux, I swapped `-ro` for `-rw` and added to the end `single`. This allowed me to boot Ubuntu, but I couldn't find out how to fix my problem with
classic boot, without changing boot parameters.

Method for boot mentioned above turned out to not be a Swiss knife - sometimes I got stuck onto log in screen and could not enter Ubuntu after entering correct password, and had to reboot several times to finally enter the system (number of needed reboots was everytime different). Then  one time I booted normally, after waiting for like a minute on GRUB dualboot screen, but it was only once and could not reproduce it.

I will be grateful for any suggestions on how to get rid off my booting problem, what tools should I use to diagnose where is the problem, etc.. I already used app `Boot Repair`, but it did not help. I will include log files here, and I would be grateful for anyone to look into them and help my find what should I fix (as it says some errors which are probably not boot related, and I don't know which is the precise one causing the problem) :
[boot -3](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7Xz3bqc8jN/)
[boot -2](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5ZQ3qvzqtc/)
[boot -1](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/79Br7wZtdz/)
[current_boot](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5wgQttn8C7/)

Comment: You cannot reboot with duplicate UUIDs. With Ubuntu often easier just to reinstall & restore settings, apps & data from your backup. Good test that backup is complete as you still have old drive to add any missing backup data. Windows also does not work from external drives, license is for one system only. But with UEFI the Product key is in UEFI, which allows you to reinstall. Clone may be easier with Windows, but then have to remove old drive.